# MatLab - Error using run => Input argument is undefined

Tags: matlab

As a MatLab newbie, I have problems running the following script:

```
function [ newarray ] = reshapeIm( array, period )
%reshapeIm(array, period) Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here


le = length(array);
fra = le/period;
array = [array, zeros(1, ceil(fra)*period-le)];

newarray = reshape(array', period, []);

end


load('1200rpm_shak3.mat');

cRounds = 54;

mylength = 100;
thetas = (1:cRounds*mylength).*2*pi/mylength;
thetas0 = (1:mylength).*2*pi/mylength;

figure; 
plot(z1(1:300), '.-');
plot(z2(1:300), '.-');

z1s = z1;
z2s = [z2(mylength/4+1:end) z2(1:mylength/4)];
z3s = [z3(mylength/2+1:end) z3(1:mylength/2)];
z4s = [z4(mylength*3/4+1:end) z4(1:mylength*3/4)];

dr = 1/4.*(z1s+z2s+z3s+z4s); % gemittelt
drs = reshapeIm(dr, mylength);
drs_std = std(drs, 1, 2);
drs_meanstd = mean(drs_std);


figure;
polar(thetas, 250000+200*dr);

figure;
polar(thetas0', 250000+200*mean(drs,2));
```

The command window says:

```
??? Error using ==> run
Input argument 'array' is undefined.
```

I suppose, that's because the script was written for a newer MatLab, but I use 5.3.

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: Are you calling the function with inputs, i.e. `reshapeIm(m,n)` for some vector `m` and number `n`? Or are you just clicking the run button in the Matlab editor?

Comment: What do you mean with question posers? I think it's insultive.

Comment: That wasn't in any way intending to insult you. I honestly thought that what you were encountering was a common problem that I've seen in the past, and it was a small inside joke to David about it. Rereading your problem and seeing the solution, I realize it isn't, so I apologize if I have offended you. Good luck btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions need to be in their own files.  You cannot define functions within a script file.  So, to get your code to work at all, you need to move the function that is at the top of your file (which I copied below) into its own file.  Name the file "reshapeIM.m" and save it in the same directory where you are doing your work.

```
function [ newarray ] = reshapeIm( array, period )
%reshapeIm(array, period) Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here


le = length(array);
fra = le/period;
array = [array, zeros(1, ceil(fra)*period-le)];

newarray = reshape(array', period, []);

end
```

Then, after removing the function from your script, save your script and run it again.  This should solve the problem with regards to the function.  You may have other errors, but this should take care of the error that you reported.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about having to have separate files for functions. I'll give it a try today.